# SignalR Unexpected response code: 500

Tags: c#, json, signalr, signalr-hub

When I use the JsonSerializer option of

```
_connection.JsonSerializer.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
```

I get an error on `_connection.Start()`
{"StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:\r\n{\r\n  Date: Tue, 04 Mar 2014 12:26:26 GMT\r\n  Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0\r\n  Content-Length: 0\r\n}"}

when I use this option every thing works fine
    _connection.JsonSerializer.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto

Comment: See the stacktrace info on the server side to debug it better. maybe open up your `Immediate Window`(CTRL+ALT+I)(IIRC) to find out what's happening

Comment: The message is not being passed to the server side

Comment: @Shachaf.Gortler I'm having a similar issue and would value any direction you have on solving this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to enable detailed errors for server which are off by default.  I enable them in debug mode only

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace MvcProject.App_Start
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();

#if DEBUG
            hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
#endif
            app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
```

Then the error should be pretty self explanatory after that.

Also check that you have a version of JSON.net that fixes this bug:
[JsonSerializer does not appear to respect TypeNameHandling property correctly](http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/21215)

Comment: I'm using json.net version 6.0.0.0

Comment: not that so, unless it's a regression.  have you more details on the actual server error?

Comment: No additional data This what the client sends , {http://localhost:8080/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.3&connectionData={"$type":"System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Hubs.HubProxy, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client]], mscorlib],[Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Hubs.HubRegistrationData, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client]], System.Core","$values":[{"$type":"Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Hubs.HubRegistrationData, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client","Name":"QRCSignalRServer"}]}}

Comment: never had to use TypeNameHandling.All, out of curiousity why do you?  as a guess does the object your sending have named property in the json for all values?